# What happens when auth token expires while uploading to firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have an application where users can upload multiple large video files (in GB) simultaneously and sometimes, for some, over slow networks. There's also a storage.rules in place to ensure that only authenticated users can upload video files and that a file been uploaded is of the right content-type.

The issue is that the uploads fail after a while (E:400), sometimes after 54mins, leaving me curious as to whether it was about the file size or upload timeout. But since I'm able to upload these files over fast network, it rules out file size. Now, I wonder if, in addition to timeout, the auth token sent to firebase storage (GCS) when the upload started could expire and cause the upload to fail?

This is all the error (exception) message I got.

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Comment: _"or upload timeout. But none of these is the problem because when I try to run the upload myself using same files on very fast network"_ I don't understand. How do you know it's not a upload timeout if you test it on a very fast network? On a very fast network you won't reach the timeout.

Comment: First step, use tools that help you test uploads and downloads. You can slow down traffic on fast networks, insert delays between packets, etc. Google search for one. Next, show your code as the behavior will depend on how you are uploading. Access Tokens expire after one hour, any requests made after that time will fail. Streaming uploads are authorized when the API requests start. AFAIK, streaming uploads do not fail once started due to token timeout. However, multi-gigabyte uploads should not be using streaming uploads and instead should use Composite Objects or at least resumable uploads.

Answer (score 1):

The user's ID token is automatically refreshed by the Firebase SDK, and an upload should be able to continue when this happens.

The only case I can think of where that isn't the case, is when the refresh of the ID token fails - such as when the user account has been disabled. If that isn't the case, I'd first look elsewhere for possible courses. And either way: I recommend checking the Network tab of your browser's developer tools for any relevant HTTP calls around the time you get the error message.